# Unable to display doughnut chart using chartjs in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to display a doughnut chart in my react application using chartjs. This is my chart.js file:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
    import Chart from "chart.js";
    
    const Chart = () => {
      const cleanData = async () => {
        data = {
          labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [120, 340, 560, 230, 100],
              backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56",
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
              ],
              hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56",
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
              ],
            },
          ],
        };
        return data;
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Doughnut data={cleanData} width={400} height={400} />
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Chart;
```

And this is my Dashboard.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "../Chart/Chart";

const Dashboard = (props) => {
return(
<div>
<Chart />
</div>
)
}
```

I intend to get data from api inside the cleanData method and process the data before displaying the chart. To keep things simple I am using a hardcoded data to see how the data is displayed. However the chart is not getting displayed. The canvas is created but the chart is not visible. If I move the data outside the cleanData method then the chart gets displayed. Am not sure where I am going wrong. Please assist me in solving this. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Try to define `redraw` as follows `<Doughnut data={cleanData} redraw width={400} height={400} />`

Comment: @uminder When I am trying this it gives me the error - Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '1' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.

Comment: Does answer help you? @shiny

Comment: @Danial I solved the issue by using useState hook to set the data after processing the data received from the API and then the graph is displayed.